# Should I use Hammer.js if I only need swipeleft

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, hammer.js

In my website I only want to open sidebar menu on swipeleft. I don't want to use Hammer.js (7.34KB) only for this functionality.
Is there any other option available?
I'll use this code to close the menu:

```
$("#page-content-wrapper").on("touchstart", function() {
      wrapper.removeClass("toggled");
    });
```

And I'm using this code to open the menu (that I don't wanna use):

```
  Hammer(document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper")).on("swiperight", function() {
      wrapper.addClass("toggled");
    });
```

Comment: Please provide us specific questions related to your problem. Opinionated answers and recommendations are off topic for SO.